# plotting a 2d wave function in maxima with respect to some temporal domain

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I'd like to know how to plot a wave function *u(x,t)*, which is defined on spatial domain *x* and temporal domain *t* by using **wxMaxima**. Please help me with the code if we set *x=[-5:5], t=[0:10]* and we would like the function to be plotted and moved temporally in one figure?

For example, let *u(x,t)=sin(x+t)*.

Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe it would help others understand what's going on if you say more about what you're trying to accomplish. Do you mean you want a three dimensional plot? i.e. with coordinates (t, x, u(x, t)). Or you want an animated image? Or something else?

Comment: An animated image. I'd like to draw a 2-d plot, i.e x vs u(x,t) and it moves over time.

Comment: I'd like to thank @RobertDodier and everyone who give it a try to answer my question.

I just have solved the problem by using this code:
with_slider_draw(t,makelist(t,t,0,1,0.1),explicit(sin(x+t),x,0,4));